# Preventing twitter bootstrap carousel autosliding using data-interval="false" does not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following bootstrap 3 carousel:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <span style="margin-left: -7px;px;color:#C0BEBE;font-size: 25px;" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
      1
    </span>
  </span>
  <span style="margin-left: -7px;px;color:#C0BEBE;font-size: 25px;" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
      2
    </span>
  </span>
  <span style="margin-left: -7px;px;color:#C0BEBE;font-size: 25px;"  data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
      3
    </span>
  </span>
  <span style="margin-left: -7px;px;color:#C0BEBE;font-size: 25px;"  data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
      4
    </span>
  </span>
  <!-- <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li> -->
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">

    <div class="carousel-caption">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">

    <div class="carousel-caption">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">

    <div class="carousel-caption">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">

    <div class="carousel-caption">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have the data-interval="false" but my carousel is always autosliding, I want the slide change only when the user press the buttons with number 1, 2, 3 o 4 but I can make it stop.

I also try:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false,
    wrap: true,
    pause: true,
});

$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false,
});

$('.carousel').carousel({
    pause: true,
});

$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false,
    pause: true,
});
```

I check my webinspector and I don't have any javascript error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your markup is wrong

remove `data-ride="carousel"` from your markup

Comment: Thanks, I already tried, but I does not work. But I remove the class carousel and It works, so thanks for the idea